# How to display group by(department) value outside the table in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services

I am working on ssrs can someone tell me How to display group by(department) value outside the table in ssrs when page break is set on groups ?

Actually i want to show the department name on top of S.no,Computer etc row which is set to Repeat on new Page:

[image]

in image i want to display PROJECT MANAGEMENT on top of table and that name should be changed accordingly(department vice) when navigate to next page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the department name is in your table somewhere, you can hide it if you don't want to see it in the output. Make a note of the TextBox name by looking at it's properties (let's say it's called DeptName)

Then in the page header, add a textbox and set it's expression to reference the textbox in the main part of the report using it's name (in our case DeptName) like this.

=ReportItems!DeptName.Value

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

1. Insert your table in List component then set list **`GROUP BY "Project Management" Column`**
2. Set Tablix Use `GROUP BY "Project Management" Column`

See image below

But I'm not sure Project Management column are repeat on other page

Hope it Help.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time actually the issue was resolved by setting the textbox field name to DeptName and put the new textbox in page header by calling DeptName expression. =ReportItems!DeptName.VAlue is only working in page header..

Comment: can you please tell me about that case that how i sum the value only from specific department my formula is : =RunningValue(iif(Right(Fields!TECHINFO1.Value, Len(Fields!TECHINFO1.Value) - InStr(Fields!TECHINFO1.Value, " "))="P 4, 3.0 GHz", 1,0), Sum, "Details") .... where should i put AND statement to IT department should be count and sum..thank you

Comment: @MAKNiazi you should use IIF again when your first condition is true for example  =IIF(...<condition>....., IIF(...<department IT> , do something if IT Dept and first condition is True , do something if not IT and first condition is true) , do something if not match first condition)